# 'useragent not available file operations may not be optimized' error when activating SP 2013 workflow feature

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-server, error, feature-activation

I have a staging environment where I restored a Production backup file. The site works fine. However when I deploy my custom SP 2013 workflow and activate the workflow feature, I get the below mentioned error in my ULS logs.

```
UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.CreateCobaltStreamContainer(SPFileStreamStore spfs, ILockBytes ilb, Boolean copyOnFirstWrite, Boolean disposeIlb) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.SetInputLockBytes(SPFileInfo& fileInfo, SqlSession session, PrefetchResult prefetchResult) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.CreateFromDocumentRowset(Guid databaseId, SqlSession session, SPFileStreamManager spfstm, Object[] metadataRow, SPRowset contentRowset, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd, Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetWebPartPageContent(Uri pageUrl, Int32 pageVersion, PageView requestedView, HttpContext context, Boolean forRender, Boolean includeHidden, Boolean mainFileRequest, Boolean fetchDependencyInformation, Boolean& ghostedPage, String& siteRoot, Guid& siteId, Int64& bytes, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, Byte& level, Object& buildDependencySetData, UInt32& dependencyCount, Object& buildDependencies, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& redirectUrl, Boolean& ObjectIsList, Guid& listId) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.FetchWebPartPageInformationForInit(HttpContext context, SPWeb spweb, Boolean mainFileRequest, String path, Boolean impersonate, Boolean& isAppWeb, Boolean& fGhostedPage, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, SPFileLevel& spLevel, String& masterPageUrl, String& customMasterPageUrl, String& webUrl, String& siteUrl, Guid& siteId, Object& buildDependencySetData, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, String& siteRoot, String& redirectUrl, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, Boolean& objectIsList, Guid& listId, Int64& bytes) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetWebPartPageData(HttpContext context, String path, Boolean throwIfFileNotFound) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String virtualPath) 
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
    at System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection) 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage() 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) 
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error) 
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb) 
    at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) 
    at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags) 
    at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags) 
    at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus) 
    at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus) 
    at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags) 
    at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
```

**Update 1 (one more log):**

```
[Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 04/20/2015 14:48:30.90, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.0665452078676962 for Data Source=servername\staging;Initial Catalog=WSS_Content_80;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15;Application Name=SharePoint[w3wp][2][WSS_Content_80]
```

**Update 2 (Got this error after recreating the Start Service Application)**

```
Feature receiver assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c', class 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.SPWorkflowPackageFeatureReceiver', method 'FeatureActivated' for feature 'dba7e829-5e2b-40c5-8105-68746b33ef93' threw an exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ActivityValidationException: Workflow XAML failed validation due to the following errors: Cannot set unknown member 'LookupSPListItem.ItemId'. HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId: 056f7427-f724-4628-b61a-cdef4e3bc731. NodeId: S-SHP-SHK-01. Scope: /SharePoint/default/7eabb605-2300-4b23-b758-fbd88b3ab02c/e8e06602-c471-4fe8-b076-79d86bbca942. Client ActivityId : f464fa9c-5ed3-3022-9eb2-3b00a6271e36. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
    at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
    at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult result)
    at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)
    at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowManagementClient.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)
    at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ActivityManager.Publish(ActivityDescription description, Boolean overwriteXClassName, Boolean terminateDependentInstances)
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowManagementClient.PublishActivity(String serviceGroupName, ActivityDescription activity, Boolean overwriteXClass, Nullable`1 terminateInstances)
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowDeploymentProvider.PublishActivity(FabricWorkflowManagementClient client, ActivityDescription activityDefinition, String serviceGroupName)
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowDeploymentProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5.<PublishDefinition>b__4()
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceContextExtensions.InvokeWithEcosystemRetry(WorkflowServicesContext context, EcosystemRequiredMethod method)
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowDeploymentProvider.PublishDefinition(WorkflowDefinition workflowDefinition)
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowDefinitionStorageEventReceiver.PublishDefinition(SPItemEventProperties properties) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.SPWorkflowPackageFeatureReceiver.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.DoActivationCallout(Boolean fActivate, Boolean fForce)
```

**Update 3 (I made the logged in account as db_owner of the content DB)**

```
Application error when access /_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx, Error=Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ActivityValidationException: Workflow XAML failed validation due to the following errors: Cannot set unknown member 'LookupSPListItem.ItemId'. HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId: 056f7427-f724-4628-b61a-cdef4e3bc731. NodeId: S-SHP-SHK-01. Scope: /SharePoint/default/7eabb605-2300-4b23-b758-fbd88b3ab02c/e8e06602-c471-4fe8-b076-79d86bbca942. Client ActivityId : f464fa9c-5ed3-3022-9eb2-3b00a6271e36. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
    at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
    at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult result)
    at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)
    at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowManagementClient.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)
    at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ActivityManager.Publish(ActivityDescription description, Boolean overwriteXClassName, Boolean terminateDependentInstances)
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowManagementClient.PublishActivity(String serviceGroupName, ActivityDescription activity, Boolean overwriteXClass, Nullable`1 terminateInstances)
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowDeploymentProvider.PublishActivity(FabricWorkflowManagementClient client, ActivityDescription activityDefinition, String serviceGroupName)
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowDeploymentProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5.<PublishDefinition>b__4()
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceContextExtensions.InvokeWithEcosystemRetry(WorkflowServicesContext context, EcosystemRequiredMethod method)
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowDeploymentProvider.PublishDefinition(WorkflowDefinition workflowDefinition)
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowDefinitionStorageEventReceiver.PublishDefinition(SPItemEventProperties properties)   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.SPWorkflowPackageFeatureReceiver.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.DoActivationCallout(Boolean fActivate, Boolean fForce) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternalWithName(Guid featureId, Int32 compatibilityLevel, String featureName, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly, Boolean fIgnoreMissing, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.FeatureActivator.ActivateFeature(Guid featid, Int32 compatibilityLevel, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.FeatureActivatorItem.ToggleFeatureActivation() 
    at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

**Update 4 (Ran the stsadm -o activatefeature and got the below mentioned error again**

```
Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ActivityValidationException: Workflow XAML failed validation due to the following errors:
Cannot set unknown member 'LookupSPListItem.ItemId'. HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId: 056f7427-f724-4
628-b61a-cdef4e3bc731. NodeId: S-SHP-SHK-01. Scope: /SharePoint/default/7eabb605-2300-4b23-b758-fbd88b3ab02c/e8e06602-c4
71-4fe8-b076-79d86bbca942. Client ActivityId : f464fa9c-5ed3-3022-9eb2-3b00a6271e36. ---> System.Net.WebException: The r
emote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowManagementClient.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ActivityManager.Publish(ActivityDescription description, Boolean overwriteXClassName, Bo
olean terminateDependentInstances)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowManagementClient.PublishActivity(String serviceGroupName, Acti
vityDescription activity, Boolean overwriteXClass, Nullable`1 terminateInstances)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowDeploymentProvider.PublishActivity(FabricWorkflowManagementCli
ent client, ActivityDescription activityDefinition, String serviceGroupName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowDeploymentProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5.<PublishDefinition>b__4(
)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceContextExtensions.InvokeWithEcosystemRetry(WorkflowServicesCo
ntext context, EcosystemRequiredMethod method)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowDeploymentProvider.PublishDefinition(WorkflowDefinition workfl
owDefinition)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowDefinitionStorageEventReceiver.PublishDefinition(SPItemEventProperti
es properties)
```

Any suggestions to fix the error? **Where should I start?**

Comment: any other error you are seeing beside this useragent?

Comment: I have an update :)

Comment: are you getting any error on site? or you just wondering about this error? both error you mentioned are very much generic.

Comment: I guess in the log should be there something more

Comment: I have a SP 2013 workflow feature to be activated, when I do the activation via the browser I get this error.

Comment: Added a new question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138924/cannot-set-unknown-member-lookupsplistitem-itemid-error-on-workflow-feature-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find a solution.. However I don't know how practical it is. This is what I did:

1. Installed Visual Studio 2012 on my Staging. Updated it with 'Update
   4'.
2. Installed office tool for VS 2012.
3. Got the work flow code and deployed it via Visual Studio. (And the
   deployment worked).
4. Retracted the solution via Visual Studio.
5. Added the .wsp files manually via STSADM command and activated the
   features successfully.

Since it was the staging environment, I had the liberty of rebooting the server many times.

**Update**
I guess Visual Studio irons out the configuration kinks that we face. Not a pretty solution at all. But hey it does the job!

Comment: Had to perform this on my production as well. It worked smooth.

Answer (score 1):

Try recreating State Service Application by executing following script:

```
$serviceApp = New-SPStateServiceApplication -Name "State Service"

New-SPStateServiceDatabase -Name "StateServiceDatabase" -ServiceApplication $serviceApp

New-SPStateServiceApplicationProxy -Name "State Service Proxy" -ServiceApplication $serviceApp -DefaultProxyGroup
```

Comment: Got an error after this: Please see update 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Flush the BLOB cache.

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication "<WebApplicationURL>"
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingCache]::FlushBlobCache($webApp)
Write-Host "Flushed the BLOB cache for:" $webApp
```

[Flush the BLOB cache](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg277249.aspx)

Comment: Ran this and got the same error :(

Comment: no other errors around?

Comment: Nothing that I can see.. Lets me look some more.. anything in specific that I need to look for?

Comment: I have an update @nk-sp